# Weird .htaccess behaviour

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my .htaccess-content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

#Rewriting /profile.php?name=XY to /player/XY
RewriteRule ^player/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]

#Remove .php file ending
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

If I am browsing to `my-domain/player/XY` it redirects me to `player.php?name=XY` (and prints an internal server error because player.php doesn't exist) instead of showing the profile.

But if I change it to
`RewriteRule ^player/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]` and open `my-domain/playera/XY` it works fine.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're getting that error since the first rule should match `/player/XY`. But you can probably add a few conditions to your php rule to ensure that *it* is rewriting correctly:

```
#Remove .php file ending
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This fixed the internal server error when I browse to my-domain/player/XY (which redirects to player.php?name=XY) -> now it shows the 404 page

Comment: @Kombustor Why is it redirecting to `/player.php?name=XY`? You have an internal rewrite that rewrites it to `/profile.php?name=XY`.